How to summarise data using CTE
I am trying to get a summary for event participants given an event_code. If the event is a parent event, the summary should be based on all the child events. If it is a single event (is not a parent and doesn't have a parent) the summary is based on the single event.
Thanks in advance!
Tables (https://i.sstatic.net/flMqjD6t.png)
WITH selectedEvent  AS (
    SELECT
        event.Event_code              AS Event_code,
        event.parent_code        AS parent_code,
        attguest.attended        AS attevent,
        cont.gender AS Gender
    FROM
        event event
        INNER JOIN EventAttendance att 
        ON event.event_code = att.event_code
        INNER JOIN EventGuestAttendance  attguest 
        ON att.Event_attendance_code = attguest.Event_attendance_code
        LEFT JOIN contact cont
        ON attguest.Contact_code=cont.Contact_code
        WHERE attguest.Contact_code is not null
        AND attguest.Attended='1' 
        --
        AND event.event_code=(Parent event or single event)
)
SELECT
    eOne.eOneID,
    eone.eOneParent
    
FROM selectedEvent eOne

I created the query above to get all event participants, but still having issues with the query

Please read How To Make A Minimal Example and improve your question. We do not use images or links in the questions because no one can copy the data to try out a solution. Provide all relevant data as tables with text or directly create a fiddle.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, not as images); an explanation of the logic you wish to implement (again as text, not embedded into an image that is inaccessible to people using screen readers); and the expected output for that sample data (again, as text, not images).

Your sample data does not appear to match the expected results. For Event 1 (with child Event 2), Luigi and Mario attended and Jim did not attend so the total attendance should be 2 (not 3) and there should be no female attendees. For event 3 (with child Event 4), Diana, Jessica and Rose attended, Joshi did not and Rose is not a contact so the total should be 2 (both female).

If you need the count of children at each level you will need to collect the path to be able to group by common subpath. Also the solution will be easier to write if you define a view joining your tables, with only the columns of interest: event_code, parent_code, gender.

You want to use a hierarchical query to find all the descendents in the Event table and then JOIN to that and then use conditional aggregation to COUNT the contacts of each gender.
Something like:
SELECT COUNT(c.contact_code) AS total_contact_attendance,
       COUNT(CASE c.gender WHEN 'Female' THEN c.contact_code END) AS female,
       COUNT(CASE c.gender WHEN 'Male' THEN c.contact_code END) AS male
FROM   (
         SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT event_code AS root_event_code,
                event_code
         FROM   event
         START WITH event_code = 1
         CONNECT BY PRIOR event_code = parent_code
       ) e
       INNER JOIN EventAttendance a
       ON e.event_code = a.event_code
       INNER JOIN EventGuestAttendance g
       ON a.Event_attendance_code = g.Event_attendance_code
       LEFT JOIN contact c
       ON g.Contact_code = c.Contact_code
WHERE  g.Contact_code is not null
AND    g.Attended = 1
GROUP BY e.root_event_code

Note: this is untested because your data is in an image, which is a format that we cannot easily access.
Also note: You do not need a sub-query factoring clause (CTE).
